# Inno Setup, is it possible to invoke a second time Initialize() on a Page at runtime?

Tags: inno-setup

I have a `TInputDirWizardPage` created within `InitializeWizard()` e.g.

```
DataFolderPage: TInputDirWizardPage;
DataFolderPage := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectDir, 'Caption', 'Description', 'Caption', True, 'mydatafolder');
```

I set the parameter **AppendDir** to **True**, at page creation.
Later on, at runtime, within function `NextButtonClick()` i decide that parameter **AppendDir** must be **False** but if i try to call `Initialze()`, compilation fails with message **Unknown identifier 'INITIALIZE'** e.g.

```
DataFolderPage.Caption := 'new caption'; // compiles ok
DataFolderPage.Initialize('new SubCaption', False, 'blah'); // Unknown identifier 'INITIALIZE'
```

Anyone knows why I cannot call method `Initialize()` again?

Comment: I think you'll find that despite all its complexity InnoSetup is not all that flexible. It tends to like things being done the "right way" and what you want is more of a hack. Best of luck.

Comment: I do not know Pascal but after searching inno source code i found out that (ScriptDlg.pas) `TInputDirWizardPage` is a `class(TWizardPage)` and `procedure Initialize(const SubCaption: String; const AppendDir: Boolean; const NewFolderName: String);` is **public**. Why this does not work? Any Pascal Gurus out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TInputDirWizardPage` class (and its bases classes) do not have a public `Initialize` method (See the Support Classes Reference in the help), and it has no property to set the `AppendDir` value.

The best way to do this is to pass false to the page to not append the directory and add it yourself when you retrive the entered path from the page.